# Recibir parámetro LocalDateTime en webservice Java con SOAP

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo un WebService que se comunica con sql para hacer la inserción en SQL de unos datos. Cuando hago un "Test Web Service", el mismo funciona correctamente e introduce los valores en la base de datos. El problema se genera cuando llamo el web service desde una app hecha con JavaFx, ya que me coloca los datos que son de tipo `LocalDateTime` haciendo referencia a una instancia que el mismo crea y no al paquete `java.time`. Es decir el web service es:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "insertUser")    
public void insertUser(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password, 
          @WebParam(name = "domain") String domain, @WebParam(name = "usernametoinsert") String usernametoinsert, 
          @WebParam(name = "fullname") String fullname, @WebParam(name = "passwordtoinsert") String passwordtoinsert,
          @WebParam(name = "domaintoinsert") String domaintoinsert, @WebParam(name = "email") String email,
          @WebParam(name = "lastlogin") LocalDateTime lastlogin, @WebParam(name = "blocked") boolean blocked,
          @WebParam(name = "createddate") java.time.LocalDateTime createddate, @WebParam(name = "createduser")
                    String createduser, @WebParam(name = "grantlevel") int grantlevel )
```

Y cuando lo uso en la app (de forma asíncrona), crea lo siguiente:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for localDateTime complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="localDateTime">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "localDateTime")
public class LocalDateTime {
}
```

Y no sé cómo modificarlo, ya que se supone que el web service espera una fecha de tipo `LocalDateTime`, y no una instancia de esa clase que se genera automáticamente.

Comment: ¿qué JDK usas para la app JavaFX?

Comment: El asunto es que LocalDateTime no es un objeto serializable por lo cual no es posible pasarlo a través de webservice, para estos casos yo creo un formato de fecha standar para el web service y para el cliente, del lado del web service convierto la fecha a string en el formato definido y al lado del cliente lo recibo como string y de acuerdo al formato definido lo convierto en fecha si es el caso

Comment: @isaac https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html: `public final class LocalDateTime
extends Object
implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDateTime<LocalDate>, Serializable`. Enfásis en **implements Serializable**.

Comment: @SJuan76 tienes razón, hice un demo con objetos que tienen tipos de datos LocalDateTime y no presentan inconvenientes.

Comment: La version del JDK es JDK15. Bueno habia pensado en esa solucion,  recibir la fecha en el web service como String, y hacer los ajustes para enviarla a la Bd. Muchisimas gracias por su pronta respuesta y por su ayuda.